# Estou com um problema para usar split() em diferentes condições no python

Tags: python, if, split

```py
print("Qual a chave do sistema? Qual o valor a ser pago? Qual a forma de pagamento (vista/débito (VD) ou pago crédito (PC))? Quantas parcelas? (Digite separado por espaços!)")
C = (input())
coisas = C.split(' ')
chave = str(coisas[0])
valor = int(coisas[1])
forma_pagamento = str(coisas[2])
numero_parcelas = int(coisas[3])
if(coisas[0] != 'DINA-A-LOJA-FINA'):
  print("ERROR: Chave Incorreta")
if(coisas[1] <= 1000):
  if(coisas[2] == 'VD'):
    print(valor_final = coisas[1]*0.88)
  else:('valor_final' == coisas[1]*0.9)
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 9     if(coisas[0] != 'DINA-A-LOJA-FINA'):
> 10    print("ERROR: Chave Incorreta")
> ---> 11    if(coisas[1] <= 1000):
> 12    if(coisas[2] == 'VD'):
> 13    print(valor_final = coisas[1]*0.88)
>
> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: na linha 11: "<=" não funciona com str e int. é o que tá escrito.

Comment: Aqui `valor = int(coisas[1])` você fez a conversão de tipo mas não usa esse valor. Talvez aqui `if(coisas[1] <= 1000)` fosse onde pretendesse o usar assim `if(valor  <= 1000)` e também nos outros lugares onde usou  `coisas[1]`.

Answer (score -1):

Existem ao todo 5 problemas no seu código.

**Problema 1**

É simples resolver. A questão é que você não pode comparar uma string com um número. Como assim? Então, apesar de parecer que ambos `1` e `'1'` são números, o `'1'` é do tipo string, enquanto `1` é do tipo inteiro. A solução é transformar `coisas[1]` para número.

```
if(int(coisas[1]) <= 1000):
```

**Problemas 2 e 3**

São similares ao Problema 1. Você apenas tem que transformar os outros `coisas[1]` em número:

```
print("Qual a chave do sistema? Qual o valor a ser pago? Qual a forma de pagamento (vista/débito (VD) ou pago crédito (PC))? Quantas parcelas? (Digite separado por espaços!)")
C = (input())
coisas = C.split(' ')
chave = str(coisas[0])
valor = int(coisas[1])
forma_pagamento = str(coisas[2])
numero_parcelas = int(coisas[3])
if(coisas[0] != 'DINA-A-LOJA-FINA'):
  print("ERROR: Chave Incorreta")
if(int(coisas[1]) <= 1000):
  if(coisas[2] == 'VD'):
    print(valor_final = coisas[1]**0.88)
```

*Nota: é sim possível uma string ser multiplicada com um número, mas ele terá que ser inteiro, e o resultado será a repetição da strings pelo número dado, exemplo:* `'oi'*3` *=* `'oioioi'`

**Problema 4**

O Problema 4 está na linha 12, `print(valor_final = int(coisas[1]*0.88)`
Lembre-se que você não pode atribuir valor a variáveis dentro do comando `print()`. Eu fiquei em dúvida se você queria criar a variável `valor_final` ou imprimir na tela o nome `valor_final`.

CASO queira criar a variável, faça assim:

```
valor_final = int(coisas[1])
print(valor_final)
```

*É importante lembrar que é desnecessário criar uma variável que nunca será utilizada. Então, você pode simplesmente fazer assim:*

```
print(int(coisas[1]))
```

CASO queira imprimir na tela o `valor_final`, faça assim:

```
print('valor_final =', int(coisas[1])*0.88)
```

*Recomendo fazer assim, pois você parece ser iniciante de Python. Mas existem outras formas, como:*

```
print('valor_final = {}'.format(int(coisas[1]*0.88)))
```

*ou*

```
print(f'valor final = {int(coisas[1]*0.88)}')
```

**Problema 5**

Não sei se foi isso que você quis fazer, mas entendi que você quis imprimir na tela o `valor_final == int(coisas[1])*0.9`. Você pode fazer assim:

```
else:
  print('valor final =', int(coisas[1])*0.9
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).